# Combobox selection control not coming out

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm working with winforms comboboxes. When I select any item in combobox I've raised an event. But control can not come outside. When I scroll the mouse the selected event changing every time.

how to prevent this?

Comment: What do you mean by "control can not come outside"?

Comment: What do you mean, "control cannot come outside?"

Comment: Jinx.....................................

Comment: yes control cannot come out side.

Comment: I believe these fine gentlemen expected more than a confirmation of the statement they need clarification on. Thus I reenact : What do you mean by "control can not come outside"?

Comment: Note sure what your problem is ..

Answer (score 0):

The mouse scrolling actually does change the item selection in the combobox and hence your event is fired, you don't want your event handling code on mouse scroll?

Comment: ya once the event got fired my event should come outside. That means the combobox item is still in the selected mode and enabled true.

Comment: @Nagu You really need to explain what do you mean by "come outside"

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that you cannot use the mouse wheel to open drop-down portion of the combobox, then you can use [ComboBox.DroppedDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.droppeddown(lightweight).aspx) property.